# Prove to compiler that object conforms to protocols after verifying conformance

Tags: swift, objectbox

I'm working on an abstraction to hide the specifics of [ObjectBox](https://swift.objectbox.io) database from my app.

```
class ObjectBoxDatabase: Database {
 
    func all<T>(of type: T.Type) throws -> [T] where T : DatabaseEntity {
        let box = self.getBox(for: T.self)
        return box?.all() ?? []
    }

    private func getBox<T>(for type: T.Type) -> Box<T>? where T : DatabaseEntity {
       switch T.self {
        case is SomeEntity.Type:
            return someEntityBox as? Box<T>
        case is SomeOtherEntity.Type:
            return someOtherEntityBox as? Box<T>
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `getBox` is just a placeholder for now, I'm planning on implementing some more advanced logic there once I figure out the generics.

My problem is that this way, the compiler is complaining when I'm calling `getBox` that `T` needs to conform `__EntityRelatable`, `EntityInspectable` and `T.EntityBindingTypeEntityType == T`.

```
Box<E> : CustomDebugStringConvertible where E : ObjectBox.EntityInspectable, E : ObjectBox.__EntityRelatable, E == E.EntityBindingType.EntityType
```

I think if it was only one requirement, I could cast `T` and pass it that way but since these 3 are not related, I don't know what to cast to that is all three and DatabaseEntity at the same time.

An other option I was thinking was to not return `Box<T>` from `getBox` but something else, this way `T` doesn't get restricted. The problem is I don't know what to return then as I don't have a common type (again)

My final try was, (I know from design perspective it is not a good approach at all, but I wanted to see some code running finally) to conform my `DatabaseEntity` to all those requirements and return `Box<DatabaseEntity>` but then I still get `any DatabaseEntity does not conform EntityInspectable` on the return type

**EDIT**

`someEntityBox` and `someOtherEntityBox` are `Box<SomeEntity>` and `Box< SomeOtherEntity>` respectively where those entities conform to the `Entity` protocol from ObjectBox

The database entity protocol is just an empty protocol for now

```
 protocol DatabaseEntity {}
```

Comment: " to conform my `DatabaseEntity` to all those requirements and return `Box<DatabaseEntity>`". IMO that is the best. Can you show the code for that? Also how are `someEntityBox` and `someOtherEntityBox` declared? What are their types?

Comment: I took a quick look at the documentation and I don't understand why you aren't using the Store class and the `box(for:)` method.

Comment: I've added the type of those Boxes to the question.
About conforming `DatabaseEntity` to those requirements: I'm not sure how to proceed about the third one where `EntityBindingType.EntityType` should be `T` but anyways even the first conformance fails on the `getBox` side:
`protocol DatabaseEntity: EntityInspectable, __EntityRelatable {}`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I will use that directly in the final implementation. For now I have to use `getBox` as a proxy to gradually integrate this new class in my app.. But anyways it has the same issue. `T.EntityBindingType.EntityType should be T`

Comment: Does it give the same issue if you use `Entity` instead as the requirement for `T`?

Comment: No but Entity comes from ObjectBox and using it would defeat the whole purpose of this class, Hiding the specifics of the database from the app

Comment: I mean for this, I would have to change the Database protocol to also use Entity as requirement

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/k5n3kbqfzzcbvdm7yvfp63npb4), where I replaced the multiple requirements for `E` with `CustomStringConvertible and `Hashable`. The code compiles just fine. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Wait, did you make `getBox` return `Box<DatabaseEntity>?`? Why did you change the return type from `Box<T>?` to *that*?

Comment: So then the problem is with the protocol DatabaseEntity which is not included in the question?

Comment: I've created [the fiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/a3wtosqblbh6tk4mrwtwmjdz2i). @Sweeper Yes, just to try to remove T from the return type to avoid constraints on it..

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It Is just an empty protocol for now. Yes, I've tried ad one point to make It conform to those requrirements, but as I said, it wasn't working and I don't like this solution anyways because it includes things form ObjectBox in the protocol

Comment: `SomeEntity` and `SomeOtherEntity` are protocols? This is never going to work then. [Protocols don't conform to other protocols.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/5133585). Why are they protocols?

Comment: You need to include `Entity` somehow in the implementation anyway. Maybe you need an associated type in your protocol and then in the implementation you say that the associated type for ObjectBoxDatabase is `Entity`.

Comment: @Sweeper they are not. My bad, sorry. They are structs. [updated](https://swiftfiddle.com/p4xbuwxrs5gu7hqpxl6yucxwuu)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Problem is, Entity on its own does not conform to those 3..

Comment: @Krisztian Great, now as you said, you should "conform my `DatabaseEntity` to all those requirements." That is, `protocol DatabaseEntity: EntityInspectable, __EntityRelatable {}`. Then the code compiles.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Database` and `DatabaseEntity` protocol apart from creating an abstraction? Are you creating a generic CRUD layer, are you implementing the Repository pattern or similar? Make sure you have the requirements on those 2 protocols set or your general goal clear to make it easier to solve problems like this.

Comment: So, I've tried again conforming `DatabaseEntity` to those 3 things but I didn't manage to. I think my situation is even more complicated because those protocols have associated types.. anyways, if I have to introduce ObjectBox into my protocol in one way or an other, the easiest was to add those 3 as requirements for `T` on the method. Not the best solutions but it is ok. I don't have to support multiple types of databases at once anyways, my only goal is to make it easier in the future to switch to an other db if needed so this solution is fine. Thank you for both of you!